# Django Admin - Disable field by choice

Tags: django, django-admin

I had a model like this

```
class Content(models.Model):
  name = Model.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
  type = Model.CharField(max_length=1, blank=False, null=False, choices=CONTENT_CHOICE)
  lesson = Model.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
  exam = Model.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
```

and CONTENT_CHOICE likes

```
CONTENT_CHOICE = (("1", "Lesson"), ("2", "Exam"))
```

My goal is, when the inputer insert a new record for this model from `Admin`, if the inputer select "Lesson", the field `exam` would be disable and vice versa. May you please advise me how to do it? I search some tutorial but all seem do not have any clue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must do that in the front-end of your project by using CSS and JavaScript.

**css**

```
.field-exam {
    display: none; /* this will be the initial display value */
}
```

**js**

```
type = document.getElementById('id_type');
field-exam = document.querySelector('.field-exam');

type.onchange = () => {
    if ( type.value === '1' ){
        field-exam.style.display = 'none';
    else if ( type.value === '2' ){
        field-exam.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Then, to override the admin templates you need to put them in

```
<project_root>/<app_folder>/static/<app_folder>/
```

then, in the template you have to import the new css and js

**change_form.html**

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block extrastyle %}
{{ block.super }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '<app_name>/<css_file>'%}">
{% endblock %}

{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
{{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '<app_name>/<js_file>' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

save the html file in

```
<project_root>/<app_folder>/template/admin/<app_folder>/<model_name>/
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time to helping me. May I ask that if we import the new css and js to the change_form.html of Django, would this affect all the others change_form of other models? Thanks.

Comment: Django uses the path of the file to decide when and where to override a template.
When saving in: `<project_root>/<app_folder>/template/admin/<app_folder>/<model_name>/change_form.html` it will override only the template for that specific model and app and only for the admin pages.